# Heredoc and special strings

Tags: php, heredoc

How do I add this kind of function...

```
__("go")
```

inside:

```
<<<_END
```

...without having to declare the variables before the heredoc?
It's just too time consuming.
I would like that my heredoc can read such functions `__("go")` without having to put them inside variables externally.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could butcher magic methods for this:

```
class Magic
{
    public function __call($method, $args) {
        // would seriously recommend checking whether `$method` exists :)
        return call_user_func_array($method, $args);
    }
}

$magic = new Magic;

$str = <<<EOM
Hello this should give the {$magic->time()}.
EOM;
```